# Handling Side-Effects in Async (thunk'd) Actions

Tags: redux

I have an async actionCreator which handle my app's authentication flow:

```
function createAuthenticationResponse(err, grant) {
  return {
    type: AUTHENTICATION_RESPONSE,
    payload: err || grant,
    error: Boolean(err)
  }
}

function authenticate() {

  // return a thunk.
  return dispatch => {

    // Notify the system that we are authenticating.
    dispatch({ type: AUTHENTICATE });

    // Trigger the auth flow.
    myAuthModule.authorize((err, grant) => {

      // Trigger a state-change on the outcome.
      dispatch(createAuthenticationResponse(err, grant));

      // Q: How do I handle this side-effect?
      if (!err) {
        dispatch(extractUserInfo(grant));
      }
    });
  };
}
```

My actionCreator contains business logic to extract the user info from the grant *if* the user was succesfully authenticated; should this logic live in my action creator?  If not, where should I place it, inside my reducer?

In other architectures I would bind a command to trigger on `AUTHENTICATION_RESPONSE`; but this doesn't feel like a middleware job?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're suggesting is totally sensible.
You can use Redux Thunk both for control flow and side effects.
You should never put side effects into the reducers.